# WordPress - Varying Theme and Layout Depending On Season?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently working on a WordPress website for a client regarding his ski chalet. He has asked me if it would be possible to essentially have a "Summer" and a "Winter" version of the site. They'll essentially have the same content (although they will use a different picture of the chalet on the homepage) but I need to be able to modify the website's colour scheme and rearrange menus, as well as displaying a different background picture.

My current solution to the problem seems like it should work but it is rather inelegant. I am essentially running two parallel sites on sub-domains and am going to create a landing page on the main domain that will either allow the user to click on a link to go to the version of the site they want or I'll use JavaScript or something to redirect them to the appropriate site version depending on the time of year.

I just wanted to know if anybody else had any ideas or better solutions on how I can achieve what I am trying to do. Also, I said that I THINK my solution should work, so if you know of any problems I could encounter doing it I would really appreciate it if you brought them to my attention and/or provided work-arounds.

Anyone got any ideas/thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other ideas that may be hopefully helpful to you:

1. You can switch stylesheets or
2. You can switch themes or
3. You can switch page templates.

Obviously all that depends on how much work you're willing to put in.

Comment: All good ideas, but they don't seem like they would be any less hassle than my current subdomain (in fact it could be more if my client decides to start varying content between the two site versions). I can mostly see how your ideas would all work but the real dilemma I am facing is that my client isn't code savvy and still needs to be able to modify the site himself once I have finished developing it. With custom page templates, couldn't he have a hard time changing them?

Comment: Use two themes, then. One theme for summer, another theme for winter, and the two themes can be as different as you'd like. All your client will have to do is click on the "Change Theme" button.

Comment: I like that idea for the most part and it was one I considered previously. Unfortunately, my issue is that swapping themes only changes the styling of the website. My client would still have to change the Summer picture on the home page to a Winter one as well rearranging the menus. I suppose I could make a Summer and Winter menu but that still leaves the picture problem. Do you think it would be possible for me to embed JavaScript into the page to decide which picture to load? It sounds do-able but I'm not sure how well JavaScript integrates with WordPress pages.

Comment: Had a tinker with the idea of running two parallel themes this morning and I'm facing a bit of a problem in that both the themes seem to be loading their selected theme options from the same place (presumably the parent) so when I change the colour scheme of one, it changes the other too. Again, I find myself stumped on how I can work around this short of hard-coding some styles into both themes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.

For your first problem (a different picture on the home page), that can be done easily. Create a category named, for example, 'Home Page Photo'. Then use the [WordPress Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to arrange for this category to show up on the home page displaying only the post image in a `<div>` positioned to your liking. Your client will then be able to upload, as he would usually upload any other post, the 'Winter Photo', or 'Summer Photo', and simply click on the checkbox that categorizes this post as the 'Home Page Photo'. This photo will then be displayed on the home page and that's what you want.

For your second problem (rearranging the menus), that can also easily be done. Simply create **all** the menu items in one fell swoop. For example, if the 'Winter Menu' consists of 'Training' and 'Racing', and the 'Summer Menu' consists of 'Camp' and 'Snowboard', create them all. The WordPress dashboard will then present your client with checkboxes where he can check or uncheck the menu items he wants included in the current menu.

For your third problem (the theme styles), that is also easy. You can write the exact styles you want for the 'Summer Theme' in its stylesheet file, and then write the exact styles you want for the 'Winter Theme' in its stylesheet file. If you are using a parent theme, then both the 'Summer Theme' and the 'Winter Theme' should be children of the parent theme. You **must not** edit any code in the parent theme but you are free to edit or modify both child themes to your satisfaction.

With all that, your client won't have to ever see or write a single line of code. All that he'll have to do is click on a few buttons here and there and that's something that everybody can do.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cheers for the reply! I'm using a pair of child themes of Duena and it all sounds good except it seems as though I am going to have to hard-code my colour schemes in because they seem to be drawing them from the options of the parent theme. Aside from that I see no real problems with what you are suggesting. I previously didn't realise that different menus can be set for different themes. Does the WordPress Loop work with static pages though? I thought it was for posts?